# Send command to already running process in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

In bash how can I issue a command to a running process I just started?

For example;

```
# Start Bluez gatttool then Connect to bluetooth device 
gatttool -b $MAC -I
connect # send 'connect' to the gatttool process?
```

Currently my shell script doesn't get to the `connect` line because the `gatttool` process is running.

Comment: you can try `echo "connect" | gatttool -b $MAC -I`

Comment: @mazs I need to send about 10 commands to `gatttool`. Would that still work? Could I send one long string with many different commands?

Comment: nope....in that case try using `expect`

Comment: Not sure what commands do you want to execute, but it seems like you can use `gatttool` in non-interactive mode as well, that would be simpler than writing an `expect` script. Check here for example : http://www.humbug.in/2014/using-gatttool-manualnon-interactive-mode-read-ble-devices/

Comment: i've added the `/expect` tag to your question.  click on it to search for other questions with that tag.

Comment: If you need just write or read: http://www.mathieupassenaud.fr/control-your-plugs-with-bluetooth-and-bash-scripts/. This helped me.

Answer (score -2):

This works!

you can try

```
echo "connect" | gatttool -b $MAC -I
```

Full credit to mazs.